# bypassing const char* requirement of execve()

Tags: c, exec, constants

I'm attempting to take user input and pass that as the filename to `execve()`.

I use `malloc()` to allocate enough memory for `char* filename` before I fill it with the path to the file I want executed.

`execve()`, however, requires a `const char*`, so it won't compile. Is there any way to bypass this? I've seen some people use `execve()` for shells, so I assume it would be possible to pass it a user-defined char array.
I'm not able to use `execvp()` or any of the other variants which search PATH automatically.

Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out, it was a pretty silly mistake. In the second argument I put `arg[0]` instead of `arg`. I vote to delete this post, as it's probably not going to help anyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are saying about "it won't compile since `execve()` requires a `const char*`" is nonsense. You can always pass a non-const variable to a const method parameter. So your problem should be somewhere else. Please post more code.